How to Display the Last Balance Entry per Time Period in Power BI?
I have a table of wallet journal entries, where each table represents multiple wallets. Each entry reflects either an expense or a profit, and the Amount column captures the delta. The Balance column shows the total balance of a wallet after each transaction.
I want to create a graph of the balance over time (daily, monthly, quarterly, and yearly). While I've correctly split out the dates, the issue I'm facing is that Power BI sums the Balance for each time period, which is incorrect.
In the matrix below, all quarters are being summed instead of showing the end state of the balance:


What I need is to display the last entry of the Balance for each time period as the data point on the graph, rather than summing the values. Is there a way to achieve this in Power BI?
I originally thought I could create a view in my database to aggregate the data, but when graphing, Power BI still attempts operations like sum, count, etc. on the balance values.
Additionally, the table contains balances across multiple wallet divisions. My next step would be splitting up the balances by wallet divisions, but I feel like once I figure out how to display the balance for all divisions together, splitting them out should be easy to understand.
Here is another example illustrating this:


